# Trying to auto-plot and submit points to a Google Maps for EE SafeCracker field

Tags: safecracker, javascript, google-maps-for-ee

I have a long list of entries where I'd like to plot a postcode into a Google Maps for ExpressionEngine field using a SafeCracker form. I had a semi-automated script/page that did this for me last year - it used JS to pre-fill the location field with a postcode, plotted the location on the map, then submitted the form automatically after a short delay.

This worked fine in EE 2.4.0 and Google Maps for EE 3.0.16, but when I just copied the same code into a newer site (using EE 2.5.5 and Google Maps for EE 3.3.1), it didn't work properly. The field populated okay with the postcode, and the point was plotted on the map okay, but when the automated submit was triggered, the point didn't save on the map (but the longitude and latitude fields did save). When I viewed the source, the Google Maps for EE field had a value in its textarea of 'false', rather than a array of mapping information.

If I click the submit button before it triggers automatically, it also doesn't save the mapping information in the map field. However, if I go to the form manually (without using this JS automation), I can plot points on the map and save the form manually without any issues.

Any ideas on why this isn't working?

The URL I'm using looks like this: mysite.com/extranet/geocoder/plot/28773/SW1A%202AA/automatic

Here's the code, and thanks for any advice.

```
{exp:safecracker channel="event" include_jquery="no" datepicker="no" class="extranet-form" return="/extranet/geocoder/plot/{segment_4}/{segment_5}/manual/saved" entry_id="{segment_4}"}

  <div class="highlight">

    {field:cf_event_map_location}

  </div><!--highlight-->

  <input name="cf_event_map_latitude" type="hidden" value="{cf_event_map_latitude}" />
  <input name="cf_event_map_longitude" type="hidden" value="{cf_event_map_longitude}" />
  <input type="text" name="postcode_prepopulate" value="{segment_5}" />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit Location" id="submit" class="button" />

{/exp:safecracker}

{if segment_6 == "automatic"}
  <script>
    $(function() {
      $('#gmap_geocoder').val($('input[name=postcode_prepopulate]').val().replace('%20', ' '));
      $('.geocoder button').trigger('click');
      setTimeout(function() {
        $('input#submit').trigger('click');
      }, 10000);
    });
  </script>
{/if}
```

Comment: Nothing in Google Maps for EE should have changed that would affect that. The API is solid and I haven't touched the FT (JS) for many releases now aside from some minor bug fixes. Is it possible to give me direct access so I can see this first hand? I am just wondering why upgrading would break this. I really put a lot of effort to make upgrades stable and not break things, so I definitely want to get to the bottom of this and see what's causing it. Emailing support@objectivehtml.com might be better to solve this issue.

Comment: Hi Justin. Just to clarify, the sites are different, but the new site I'm having issues with is using the same script and code to auto-fill and submit the Google Maps form as the older site was using, which is why I've been stumped about why it's not working on the newer site, and could only think it was down to EE or add-on versions/differences. Thanks for the offer to take a look, and I'll put together an email with the details.

Comment: Right, I am not against answering here, I just need to ask a series of questions to conclude an answer and this place just isn't the best format for that. :)

Comment: I still need to put this email together, but after further testing, I've narrowed down the issue to this line of the JS that I was using to pre-populate, plot, and submit the form: $('.geocoder button').trigger('click'); This line is meant to repeat the user clicking the 'Plot location' button, and on my old site, when I use the web inspector, I can see that the gmap_output_cf_event_map_location textarea field was pre-filled with the JSON array with all the Google Maps for EE location data that had been plotted. On the new site, this field has a value of 'false'. Strange.